# I need a query that will return all rows and all columns from two tables when one field is in common

Tags: mysql

I have a simple task in MySQL. I have two tables t1 and t2. Table t1 has one column in common with table t2. 
What I want is to return all the columns from both tables (order is not important) but making sure that the rows of both tables are matching based on a common field, say fieldx. However, not all the rows in table t1 have a matching row in table t2 (i.e. table t1 has much more rows, but all rows in t2 have a matching row in t1 ).

I tried to use `where` as such:

`SELECT t1.* t2.* from t1, t2 where t1.fieldx=t2fieldx`

However this returns only the number of rows as there are in table t2.

I also tried right and left joins, but couldn't get that to work either (this way not all columns of both tables were included..)

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` will give you all the rows from `t1` and if `t2` does not have an entry for it, `t2` columns will appear as `NULL`:

```
   SELECT t1.*,
          t2.* 
     FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
       ON t1.fieldx = t2.fieldx
```

Here is an <kbd>[**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de975/2/0)</kbd> of the above said, as you can see in `t2`, I've only referenced the first 3 records of `t1` hence why the rest of the `t2` information comes out `NULL`, as there is no `t2` record to that given `t1` entry.

Comment: I don't understand why it is that when I run these commands on my tables, I still only get the number of rows as there are rows in table t2. So I don't get all the rows... arghhh, been suffering on this the whole day.

Comment: @oaklander114 if you could reproduce the issue using that site on my Live Demo I might be able to see what is going on for u.

Comment: -- UPDATE: it's working. At the end I was just looking at the wrong output file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad you sorted it out ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I want is to return all the columns from both tables (order is not
>   important) but making sure that the rows of both tables are matching
>   based on a common field, say fieldx.

This query solve this:

```
SELECT t1.* t2.* FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 WHERE t1.fieldx = t2fieldx
```

Further, if the next phrase is true, you can try with LEFT OUTER JOIN too (or RIGHT).

> but all rows in t2 have a matching row in t1

```
SELECT t1.* t2.* FROM t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 WHERE t1.fieldx = t2fieldx
```